# How to read multiple images and store them on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

So this is my code so far,

```
clear;clc;
path = uigetdir(); %open directory
if isequal(path,0) 
   disp('User selected Cancel');
return
else
   disp(['User selected ', (path)]); 
end

% pathPattern = fullfile(path); 
theFiles = dir(path); %Get list of all files with desired pattern
for k = 3 :5  %Change length when needed
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(theFiles(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName)

end

a = imread(fullFileName);
```

My problem is that imread only reads one of the images from my directory, I need it to read all the images and store them in a cell array. I've tried multiple answers from the internet and none of them has worked so far.

Comment: What are the file extensions of your images? Are there patterns to the filenames you want to read from? Without them, why not just imread all files?

Comment: @Argyll I can not say what the file extensions are, unfortunately. There is a pattern, but imread only reads the last image not all.

Comment: Pull your `imread` into the loop. This way, of course it only reads the last `fullFileName` set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in a cell array inside the loop since it allows for images of different sizes. If you know in advance that the images will be of the same size, using a regular numeric array will be much faster.

```
clear, clc
path = uigetdir(); % open directory
if isequal(path,0) 
   disp('User selected Cancel');
return
else
   disp(['User selected ', (path)]); 
end

theFiles = dir(path);       % Get list of all files with desired pattern
for k = 3:length(theFiles)  % Change length when needed
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(theFiles(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1,'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName)
    a{k-2} = imread(fullFileName);
end

a
```

Comment: “using a regular numeric array will be much faster” I strongly doubt that. Because you’d have to copy the image read into the array. With a cell array there’s no copy. A single numeric array might make other processing faster, depending on how the images will be used, and would take up less memory.